# How do I expand the item set for this grammar?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, dfa, lr-grammar, lars

I have this grammar

```
E -> E + i
E -> i
```

The augmented grammar

```
E' -> E
E -> E + i
E -> i
```

Now I try to expand the item set 0

```
I0)
 E' -> .E
+E  -> .E + i
+E  -> .i
```

Then, since I have `.E` in `I0` I would expand it but then I will get another `E` rule, and so on, this is my first doubt.

Assuming that this is alright the next item sets are

```
I0)
 E' -> .E
+E  -> .E + i
+E  -> .i

I1) (I moved the dot from I0, no variables at rhs of dot)
E' -> E.
E -> E. + i
E -> i.

I2) (I moved the dot from I1, no vars at rhs of dot)
E -> E +. i

I3) (I moved the dot from I2, also no vars)
E -> E + i.
```

Then I will have this DFA

```
I0 -(E, i)-> I1 -(+)-> I2 -(i)-> I3
              |                   |
              +-(∅)-> acpt <-(∅)--+
```

I'm missing something because `E -> E + i` must accept `i + i + ..` but the DFA doesn't goes back to the I0, so it seems wrong to me. My guess is that it should have a I0 to I0 transition, but I then I don't know that to do with the dot.

Answer (score 2):

What you call the "expansion" of the item set is actually a closure; that's how it's described in all the descriptions of the algorithm I've seen (at least in textbooks). Like any closure operation, you just keep on doing the transformation until you reach a fixed-point; once you've included the productions for `E`, they're included.

But the essential point is that you're not building a DFA. You're building a pushdown automaton, and the DFA is just one part of it. The DFA is used for shift operations; when you shift a new terminal (because the current parse stack is not a handle), you do a state transition according to the DFA. But you also push the current state onto the PDA's stack.

The interesting part is what happens when the automaton decides to perform a reduction, which replaces the right-hand side of a production with its left-hand side non-terminal. (The right-hand side at the top of the stack is called a "handle".) To do the reduction, you unwind the stack, popping each right-hand side symbol (and the corresponding DFA state) until you reach the beginning of the production. What that does is rewind the DFA to the state it was in before it shifted the first symbol from the right-hand side. (Note that it is only at this point that you know for sure which production was used.) With the DFA thus reset, you can now shift the non-terminal which was encountered, do the corresponding DFA transition, and continue with the parse.

The basis for this procedure is the fact that the parser stack is at all times a "viable prefix"; that is, a sequence of symbols which are the prefix of some right sentential form which can be derived from the start symbol. What's interesting about the set of viable prefixes for a context-free grammar is that it is a *regular language*, and consequently can be recognised by a DFA. The reduction procedure given above precisely represents this recognition procedure when handles are "pruned" (to use Knuth's original vocabulary).

In that sense, it doesn't really matter what procedure is used to determine which handle is to be pruned, as long as it provides a valid answer. You could, for example, fork the parse every time a potential handle is noticed at the top of the stack, and continue in parallel with both forks. With clever stack management, this parallel search can be done in worst-case O(n<sup>3</sup>) time for any context-free grammar (and this can be reduced if the grammar is not ambiguous). That's a very rough description of Earley parsers.

But in the case of an LR(k) parser, we require that the grammar be unambiguous, and we also require that we can identify a reduction by looking at no more than `k` more symbols from the input stream, which is an O(1) operation since `k` is fixed. If at each point in the parse we know whether to reduce or not, and if so which reduction to choose, then the reductions can be implemented as I outlined above. Each reduction can be performed in O(1) time for a fixed grammar (since the maximum size of a right-hand side in a particular grammar is fixed), and since the number of reductions in a parse is linear in the size of the input, the entire parse can be done in linear time.

That was all a bit informal, but I hope it serves as an intuitive explanation. If you're interested in the formal proof, Donald Knuth's original 1965 paper (*On the Translation of Languages from Left to Right*) is easy to find and highly readable as these things go.